# fancyBox Button Helper

Tags: php, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help please.

I'm using the script below to create a 'Image Gallery' in fancyBox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
  <title>Gallery</title>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.6"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

  <script type="text/javascript">  

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'elastic',

                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });



</script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
-->
  </style>  
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; margin-left: 240px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div> 
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-left: -120px; margin-right: 50px;"> 

    <p>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :  
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);  
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source'));  
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail'));  
                  ?>
      <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a>
      <?php endfor; ?>  
    </p>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to create any of the functionality from within my fancyBox Javascript e.g. 'button helper' functionality and the title inside the image format.

I've taken the code from the 'fancyapps' page [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/)  so I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. I am relatively new to fancyBox, so perhaps these are just beginners errors.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using fancyBox 1.3.4 but you have to use fancyBox2 to use these helpers.

Second, check if your paths are correct, maybe you should change from

```
..href="fancybox/source/..
```

to

```
..href="/fancybox/source/..
```

Comment: Hi @Janis, thanks you so much for your help. I've upgraded to v2 as you suggested and it works great. Kind regards